# undefined is not an object ( evaluating '_expo.default.Constants')

Tags: react-native, expo, manifest.json

I would like to debug on my mobile/simulator and point it dynamically to API.

```
const {manifest} = Expo.Constants; 
const api = manifest.packagerOpts.dev
? manifest.debuggerHost.split(':').shift().concat(':3000')
: 'productionurl.com'


export function getEvents(){
    return fetch('http://${api}/events')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(events => events.map(e =>({ ...e, date: new Date(e.date)})));
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> undefined is not an object(evaluating'_expo.default.Constants')

Comment: import Expo, {Constants} from 'expo

Comment: I have imported the same but its reflecting me the same error.

Comment: `import * as Expo from ‘expo'`

Comment: yeah, it solved the problem Thanks @hong develop

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please  my answer choose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bring the complete module of the expo with:

```js
import * as Expo from 'expo'
```

Answer (score 15):

I work with `"sdkVersion": "35.0.0"`. It seems that Expo changed its API. They extracted and moved some parts into separate packages.
Now for this case you need to install a separate dependency:

```
npm i --save expo-constants
```

And then to import `FileSystem` object independently for your component:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are working in Snack.expo.io, if you get this error, use the code:

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
```

This worked for me.